TWinCAT3 inline monitor float variable is displayed as an ellipsis
I am using TwinCAT3 version 3.1.4026. When I monitor the float variable, it is displayed as an ellipsis, which makes it difficult to check the value. How can I set it to show the real value inline? Thank you.
enter image description here
I tried to set the monitoring string length (up to 20), but it had no effect.
